# Vue.js: How to fill a form prepopulated with data from a get request?

Tags: forms, vue.js, axios

I want to load data with a GET request and fill the data to the input data attributes at vue.js 3 like

```
<input id="name" type="text" v-bind:placeholder="$t('message.NamePlaceholder')" value="{{ name }}" required>
```

and this is my script part

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      userInformation: {},
      name: "",
   }
},
mounted () {
  this.getUserInformation();
},
methods () {
  getUserInformation() {
    this.$axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get_user_information',
    }).then(response => {this.userInformation = response.data});
    this.name = this.userInformation.Name;
   }
 },
}
```

But the input field contains only `{{ name }}`. I tried also `v-bind:value`, but this didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was that I have to set the variable `this.name` at the axios command:

```
this.$axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get_user_information',
}).then(response => {
  this.userInformation = response.data;
  this.name = this.userInformation.Name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to bind values to attributes `{{}}` are unnecessary. You can just write `v-bind:value="name"` or `:value="name"`

E.g.:

```
<input id="name" type="text" :placeholder="message.NamePlaceholder" :value="name" required></input>
```